# Why do bash "set -e" cause exit after a seeming error-free command?

Tags: bash

Without using `set -e`, the script runs as expected, with all results correctly generated.

After adding `set -e`, it exits after this command:

```
./NameOfATool > result.txt
```

When I wrap `set +e` and `set -e` around that command, then the script terminates as expected.

Why would it exit, or what might be wrong with the command?

p.s. `NameOfATool`is an executable compiled from C code. When I manually type that command, it runs ok without giving an error.

Comment: put some `echo $?` after that command for debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -e` will cause the script to exit if any command returns a non-zero exit status. (Well, there are a bunch of exceptions, but that's the general rule.) So, `./NameOfATool` apparently returns a non-zero exit status. This might mean that it actually thinks there's an error, or it might mean that the program was poorly written and doesn't report an appropriate exit status for success, or it might mean that it uses special exit-status values to report specific things (much like the standard utility `diff`, which returns 0 for "same", 1 for "different", and 2 for "error").

Answer (score 2):

Try set +e in your trap:

```
set -e;

trap 'x=$?; set +e; echo Hello; false; echo World; exit 22;' ERR

echo Testing
false
echo Never See This
```

Omit the `set +e` and you don't see the "World" as the non-zero exit code in the trap exits before the trap is completed.

Answer (score 1):

As @ruakh said, this indicates that the tool is exiting with a nonzero (=error) status. You can prevent this from exiting the script by putting it in a compound command that always succeeds:

```
./NameOfATool > result.txt || true
```

If the tool exits with a nonzero status, it runs `true`, which succeeds; hence, the entire compound command is considered to have succeeded. If the command's exit status is significant (i.e. you need to be able to tell if it exited with status 0, 1, or 2), you can either record it for later use:

```
./NameOfATool > result.txt && toolStatus=0 || toolStatus=$?
```

...or use the status directly:

```
if ./NameOfATool > result.txt; then
    # do things appropriate for exit status = 0
else
    toolStatus=$?
    # do things appropriate for exit status != 0
fi
```